# What is the use of createing an Interface array assign to instantiated object

Tags: java, interface

Here we have created an object of B and assigned it to reference variable of Interface.What does it means actually?.
The purpose of interface is to be used for implementation by classes.What can an interface do when we create its array.
What does it means actually?.

```
interface  I1{}

class A implements I1{}
class B implements I1{}
class C extends B
{}
class D{}





public class lab1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        I1 i1[] = new B[4];
        i1[0] = new A();
        i1[1] = new C();
        i1[2] = new B();
        //i1[3] = new D();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to perform the same operation on all the instances in the array (by calling some methods of that interface).

For example :

```
for (I1 inst : i1) {
    i1.doSomething (); // where doSomething() is a method declared by the interface I1
}
```

To make it less abstract, here's a more concrete example - if the interface is called `Shape` and it has a `draw()` method, you can draw all the shapes by writing :

```
for (Shape shape : shapesArray) {
    shape.draw ();
}
```

This code doesn't care if the actual instances stored in the array are Circles, Rectangles or Polygons, as long as all of them implement the `Shape` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
    I1 i1[] = new I1[4];   // Change this
    i1[0] = new A();
    i1[1] = new C();
    i1[2] = new B();
```

The first line creates an array of references to `I1` objects.

The other lines create concrete `I1` objects of type `A, C, B, D.`

---

Your code doesn't work because is not possible to assign an object of type A to a reference of concrete type B.

Answer (score 0):

You have list of **Cars** (Interface with drive method) but you dont care if it is *bmw*, *audi* or a *driverless* car. All you need is it should be able to **drive** so you can call drive() method. Check [polymorhism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) and [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [is-a&has-a testing](http://learnwithharsha.com/my-first-java-lesson-is-a-and-has-a-relationships/)